# security camera power by solar regulator

Tags: dc

i have a solar panel with regulator to run a a light as well as charge a battery. i want to add a security camera which uses a power supply of 9 volt dc and 600ma. instead of using an inverter and camera power supply would it not be more effiiceint to simply stepdown the 12 volt to 9 volt? i found a dc stepdown from 12 v to output of 9V with 2Amps. will this be okay and not damage camera?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the exact camera and the exact stepdown converter you're talking about, but in general, it sounds like it should work. The other question would be whether the solar panel puts out enough average power to support the extra load.

Comment: Thank you. the panel is 100 watts but over winter with snow cover in my absence, the 12 v battery may weaken. would this low voltage damage my cobra camera?

Comment: the converter is a inexpensive dc to dc converter

Comment: Undervoltage shouldn't damage the camera; it will either shut down or simply fail to perform at its full specifications.

Comment: Will a 9 v /2A converter damage the 9 V /600 mA input to camera? thank you in advance since I am not good at electricity but better on chemistry!

Comment: sorry, but will the 2 A overvoltage damage the 600mA camera; just want to be sure .thank you

Comment: Did you read the linked question regarding the difference between voltage and current ratings?

Comment: sorry , did not read it. I simply want to know if 2 A will damage 600 mA camera. as I said I do not understand voltage vs amperage and consequences.